# Getting ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID for my glitch URL when using XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, https, glitch-framework

I am using the POST method with XMLHttpRequest to get some information from one GLITCH URL with a NodeJS application. It is https:// and I typed the URL correctly. I am passing some parameters but nothing is wrong with that. Any help?

EDIT: I am using the new Microsoft Edge based on Chromium.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'http://www.********.glitch.me/bot?say=1');
xhr.send()
```

The actual website with the request is a https:// but the other is a http://.

Error:

*The page at ********* was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint ********. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS*

Comment: That error happens when the domain name of your request does not match the domain name the ssl certificate was issued for. This might happen if you're developing locally and using localhost. That's a case where you can ignore the error. If that's not the case you need to look at your request and the ssl certificate.

Comment: It is a https domain and I'm accessing the website with the XMLHttpRequest published; on a domain..

Comment: If you look at the ssl certificate you might find a clue. Go to the same url in your browser, click the lock, and see what the CNAME is.

Comment: I switched to HTTP as I found it was not HTTPS and then I got this error:


Mixed Content: The page at ***' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint ***'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Comment: Is the POST request to a service/website of yours, or a service/website of someone else?

Comment: Mine. I made the NodeJS bot.

Comment: I think your original question needs to be filled out with some more details. It would be best if we could reproduce the error. If you boil it down to the minimal code required to reproduce that would be great. Maybe where the request is sent from, the request itself minus private info, and the whole response less private info? In this problem the domain names are important, but you can replace them with aliases.

Comment: I added an edit which might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

glitch.me provides an ssl certificate that covers mydomain.glitch.me (a wildcard certificate *.glitch.me; see below info about URLs and ssl certificates)

Your service is using [www.mydomain.glitch.me](http://www.mydomain.glitch.me) so the ssl certificate is invalid.

You either need to install your own ssl certificate for [www.mydomain.glitch.me](http://www.mydomain.glitch.me)

OR

Recommended: change your glitch url to fit the format mydomain.glitch.me

*Info about SSL Certificates:*

Without going in to how they work, they certify that the encrypted data you receive (like a web page) came from the domain in the certificate.

You can get SSL Certificates for a specific domain or a wildcard certificate. Wildcards include any single subdomain of the main domain.

*Info about URLs:*

Consider https://api.blog.example.com/search?term=example

the protocol is https

There are 2 subdomains: api and blog

The domain is example

The top-level domain is com

The path is search

The query is term=example

This url requires an ssl certificate for api.blog.example.com

IF the url had only 1 subdomain it could use a wildcard certificate: *.example.com

The wildcard certificate would cover https://www.example.com, https://blog.example.com, https://test.example.com, but would NOT cover https://www.blog.example.com because there are 2 levels of subdomain.

Comment: What do you mean by change the format. It is following that format?

Comment: Your custom part of the domain cannot have a dot in it.  The `www.` needs to be removed.

Comment: It's a common misconception that `www.` is a standard component of a domain name. It's super common to use but it's actually called a sub-domain and it can be anything not just www.

Comment: What custom part of the domain? Do you mean the http part?

Comment: http:// is a protocol, www is a sub-domain, google is a domain name, .com is a top-level domain, /search is a path, ?something=1 is a query, and #something is a hash. You have 2 subdomains: www and the part you replaced with asterisks. The domain is glitch and the tld is me. You cannot have 2 subdomains, only 1. subdomain, domain, and top-level domain are separated by dots. A url can have many subdomains but in your case you must have only 1.

Comment: I will try this out tomorrow and if it worked I will put it as the answer.